# direct2d left bottom coordinate

Tags: 2d, direct2d

By default direct2d uses left top coordinate system. I want to write simple chart and it will be much easier for me to use left bottom coordinate system (translation, scale, rotation etc). Are there any methods or transformations to achieve this result?

I don't want to use something like canvas.height - coordinate to simulate left-bottom coordinate space because this causes a lot of troubles. Maybe there is some option I've missed or some other option to set-and-forget.
Thanks.

Comment: Left top is more logical. Just learn to use it.

Comment: You can draw your objects in left-bottom coord. system, then you can make a transform matrix to flip your result image. It is done by a scaling matrix (with y value of -1) multiplied with translation matrix (where y = canvas.height).

Comment: @zenith I have no problem with left top but left bottom will be much easier in my case because data is in left bottom. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @anton-angelov Thanks for your answers. That is how I use it now but I think there must be some simpler way )

Comment: How you imagine a simpler way than a scaling matrix ?

Comment: @peter-kostov That is why I asked this question) I know that in opengl you can change origin(and left-bottom is default) and I'm wondering if there is any out-of-box option for direct2d. For now scale*translation is the best option I see so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it seems there is no other option except of scaling matrix.